# Binomial coefficient with brackets

Tags: symbols

Is there any way to write a binomial coefficient that has brackets in place of parenthesis?

Another way to write what I want would be to get a fraction without the horizontal bar between the denominator and the numerator, and then surround it with big brackets, but is this possible?

Comment: You can use `{n \brack k}`.

Answer (score 15):

You can tap into [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\genfrac`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\stirlingii}{\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}}

\begin{document}

There is $\binom{a}{b}$ and $\stirlingii{a}{b}$ and also
\[
  \binom{a}{b} \text{ and } \stirlingii{a}{b}.
\]

\end{document}
```

`\genfrac{<ldelim>}{<rdelim>}{<width>}{<style>}{<numerator>}{<denominator>}` sets a fraction braced by `<ldelim>` and `<rdelim>` in a fraction-like style with horizontal rule of width `<width>`. The optional `<style>` can force the output to be in any of the four math styles.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm searching for, thank you!!! :D

Comment: These are known as Stirling numbers of the second kind, so maybe a better name could be `\stirlingii`